# Jquery: How to redirect all keyboard input to a textbox dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here's what I want to do, but it's not working for me for some reason:

1. A user types something anywhere on `keyup`
2. Grab the key pressed and put it in a variable named `character`
3. `textbox inputField value = inputField value + the new character variable`

A working example: http://dojin.co/
(first click outside of the login box and then just try typing anywhere)

And here's my code:

HTML:

```
<input type="text"></input>
<input type="text" id="inputField"></input>
```

JavaScript/jQuery:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  var character = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
  $('#inputField').val($('#inputField').val() + character);
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/6bujz70t/ ... or expectations need better explanation

Comment: @charlietfl thanks! it wasn't working at all like no output nothing that's really weird maybe its a problem with my Jquery file going to try replacing it...

Comment: actually it works on your live example site also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it simply with JavaScript :

```
function inputFocus(){
    document.getElementById("inputField").focus();
}
window.onkeydown = inputFocus;
```

Here is the working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/es3vba4k/)**